# Getting GIT revision # and date using ruby to update json file

Tags: ruby, json, git, rake

I have a JSON file that looks like:

```
{
   "git" : {
      "version" : "abc123",
      "date" : "2013/10/04 5:55pm"
   },
   ..
}
```

So I have a rake task the prepares my application for deployment, and I want to get the git revision # and date and update my json file with this information.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps using the backsticks command (e.g `\`git [command]\``) from within the `rake` task to execute the appropriate git command, parse the results and update the json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish this code is helpful to you.

```
require 'json'
latest_revision = `git rev-parse HEAD`
latest_revision_date = `git log -1 --format=%cd`
json_data = JSON.parse( IO.read('./json.js') )
json_data["git"]["version"] = latest_revision
json_data["git"]["date"] = latest_revision_date
f = File.open("./json.js", "w")
f.write(json_data)
f.close
```